# Zsh theme: dirty color and suffix

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to customize the Bira zsh-theme so that a clean branch is green and a dirty branch is red and has an asterisk at the end like so...

[image: custom zsh-theme]

I have gotten it so that the color changes based on the branch's state, but cannot figure out how to get the asterisk to show up at the end. Below is what I have so far. I'm very new to customizing zsh-theme files, so any help would be much appreciated!

```
# ZSH Theme - Modified from bira.zsh-theme
local return_code="%(?..%{$fg[red]%}%? ↵%{$reset_color%})"

if [[ $UID -eq 0 ]]; then
    local user_host='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[red]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}'
    local user_symbol='#'
else
    local user_host='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[cyan]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}'
    local user_symbol='$'
fi

local current_dir='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[yellow]%}%~%{$reset_color%}'
local git_branch='$(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}'

function git_prompt_info() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "$(parse_git_dirty)$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX$(current_branch)$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
}

PROMPT="
╭─${user_host}  ${current_dir}  ${git_branch}
╰─%B${user_symbol}%b "
RPS1="%B${return_code}%b"


ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="‹"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="›$reset_color"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="$fg[red]"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="$fg[green]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parse_git_dirty` function is defined in [`lib/git.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/d2725d44fce59ea7060b4d712c5739512a56882d/lib/git.zsh)

By copying that function into your file and modifying it slightly, we can achieve what you want:

```sh
function git_prompt_info() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return

  # Checks if working tree is dirty
  local STATUS=''
  local FLAGS
  FLAGS=('--porcelain')
  if [[ "$(command git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-dirty)" != "1" ]]; then
    if [[ $POST_1_7_2_GIT -gt 0 ]]; then
      FLAGS+='--ignore-submodules=dirty'
    fi
    if [[ "$DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY" == "true" ]]; then
      FLAGS+='--untracked-files=no'
    fi
    STATUS=$(command git status ${FLAGS} 2> /dev/null | tail -n1)
  fi

  if [[ -n $STATUS ]]; then
    GIT_PROMPT_COLOR="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY"
    GIT_DIRTY_STAR="*"
  else
    GIT_PROMPT_COLOR="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN"
    unset GIT_DIRTY_STAR
  fi

  echo "$GIT_PROMPT_COLOR$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX$(current_branch)$GIT_DIRTY_STAR$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
}
```

The only difference from the library function is assigning `GIT_PROMPT_COLOR` and `GIT_DIRTY_STAR` instead of echoing, and then using these in the final echo.

Comment: This accomplished exactly what I wanted to - thank you so much!